# Operation Resumability of Service (?)

Tags: architecture, containers, microservices, reactive-streams, rsocket

The `#Cloud-Native` way, guarantees the Availability of the services. The `#containers` serving the request, may die & self-heal, but the service endpoint needs to ensure the request gets served.

If the service is based on TCP socket serving custom protocol and involves complex and long running operations, do the `#Resumability` of the operation (from where a died container left) need to be supported in the service? If **YES**, what are the ways and means to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no standard way to implement long running resumable operations. The closest you can get is to use an orchestration platform like [Temporal](https://temporal.io). It allows reconnecting to already running operation (aka workflow) by its business ID. Temporal also out of the box deals with container failures seamlessly reconstructing the operation implementation state.

See [my presentation](https://youtu.be/llmsBGKOuWI) that describes the Temporal programming model.

Comment: Thanks @maxim-fateev. I shall certainly have a look at Cadence. I found an article about 'Reactive Systems' and the RSockets used in it seems to have such provision. The article's URL is :  https://blog.grapeup.com/read/reactive-service-to-service-communication-with-rsocket-load-balancing--resumability-65

Comment: It looks like they are concerned with resuming a stream. Pretty low level mechanism which doesn't directly solve the problem of disconnecting long running operation processing from process restarts.